# How can i make a placeholder image add itself if there is no image uploaded?

Tags: php

I have a php script here for adding images to the database. However, I have a problem because when I leave the image selection blank nothing is added to the database and it breaks the rest of the application. Is it possible to add something like a placeholder here, which is added if the file selection is not completed?

```
//file name is config.php
<?php
$dbHost     = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName     = "codexworld";

// Create database connection
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

// Check connection
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}
?>
```

```
//file name is dodanie_zdjecia.php


<form action="post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select Image File to Upload:
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
<?php

$dbHost     = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName     = "codexworld";


$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}
?>
```

```
//file name is post.php
<?php
include 'config.php';
$statusMsg = '';

$targetDir = "uploads/";
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    // Allow certain file formats
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf','mp3');
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){

            $insert = $db->query("INSERT into images (file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES ('".$fileName."', NOW())");
            if($insert){
                $statusMsg = "Plik: ".$fileName. "Został poprawnie dodany do posta. Przejdź na stronę główną: <a href='strona_glowna.php'>Strona główna</a>";
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "File upload failed, please try again.";
            } 
        }else{
            $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, & PDF files are allowed to upload.';
    }
}else{
    $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
}

?>
```

Comment: Usually, what is done is to have a default.jpg image in the images folder of your website, so if any record is uploaded to the database with an image field and it would remain empty, the default.jpg is automatically set.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){

 .....
}else{
$fileName='placeholderimagefilelocation'
            $insert = $db->query("INSERT into images (file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES ('".$fileName."', NOW())");

}
```

OR

```
if($image != '' ){
 your db saved file
}else{
 your placeholder file location
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).